# Open CMD as admin mode in Azure?

Tags: powershell, azure, amazon-web-services, cmd

I'm new in azure and I dont know howt to open the cmd in admin mode.I want to install Chocolatey.

Can anyone tell me?
Thanks

Comment: Yes@JasonYe-MSFT

Comment: Windows server on Azure VM?

Answer (score 1):

We can via windows search to start CMD as admin, like this:

[image]

By default, the `administrator` account does not exist, your account in group `Administrators`, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I need to open it in Azure!

Comment: Not Azure VM? Do you mean run cmd in Azure web app or other things?

Answer (score 0):

To open Command Prompt with administrative privileges, right-click the result and then click “**Run as Administrator**”.

[image]

To install Chocolatey refer "https://chocolatey.org/install".